# Eigen decomposition of Hermitian Matrix using CuSolver does not match the result with matlab

Tags: c++, cuda, eigenvalue, eigenvector, cusolver

I am following the example of eigen decomposition from here,
https://github.com/NVIDIA/CUDALibrarySamples/blob/master/cuSOLVER/syevd/cusolver_syevd_example.cu

I need to do it for Hermatian complex matrix. The problem is the eigen vector is not matching at all with the result with Matlab result.

Does anyone have any idea about it why this mismatch is happening?

I have also tried cusolverdn svd method to get eigen values and vector that is giving another result.

My code is here for convenience,

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cusolverDn.h>

#include "cusolver_utils.h"

int N = 16;
void BuildMatrix(cuComplex* input);

void main()
{
    cusolverDnHandle_t cusolverH = NULL;
    cudaStream_t stream = NULL;
    printf("*******************\n");

    cuComplex* h_idata = (cuComplex*)malloc(sizeof(cuComplex) * N);
    cuComplex* h_eigenVector = (cuComplex*)malloc(sizeof(cuComplex) * N); // eigen vector
    float* h_eigenValue = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * 4);    // eigen Value
    BuildMatrix(h_idata);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N / 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("%f + %f\t", h_idata[count].x, h_idata[count].y);
            count++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n*****************\n");

    /* step 1: create cusolver handle, bind a stream */
    CUSOLVER_CHECK(cusolverDnCreate(&cusolverH));

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&stream, cudaStreamNonBlocking));
    CUSOLVER_CHECK(cusolverDnSetStream(cusolverH, stream));

    // step 2: reserve memory in cuda and copy input data from host to device
    cuComplex* d_idata;
    float* d_eigenValue = nullptr;
    int* d_info = nullptr;

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_idata, N * sizeof(cuComplex)));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&d_eigenValue), N * sizeof(float)));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&d_info), sizeof(int)));

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpyAsync(d_idata, h_idata, N * sizeof(cuComplex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream));

    // step 3: query working space of syevd
    cusolverEigMode_t jobz = CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_VECTOR; // compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors.
    cublasFillMode_t uplo = CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER;

    int lwork = 0;            /* size of workspace */
    cuComplex* d_work = nullptr; /* device workspace*/
    const int m = 4;
    const int lda = m;

    cusolverDnCheevd_bufferSize(cusolverH, jobz, uplo, m, d_idata, lda, d_eigenValue, &lwork);

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&d_work), sizeof(cuComplex) * lwork));

    // step 4: compute spectrum
    cusolverDnCheevd(cusolverH, jobz, uplo, m, d_idata, lda, d_eigenValue, d_work, lwork, d_info);

    CUDA_CHECK(
        cudaMemcpyAsync(h_eigenVector, d_idata, N * sizeof(cuComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream));
    CUDA_CHECK(
        cudaMemcpyAsync(h_eigenValue, d_eigenValue, 4 * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream));

    int info = 0;
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpyAsync(&info, d_info, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream));

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamSynchronize(stream));

    std::printf("after syevd: info = %d\n", info);
    if (0 > info)
    {
        std::printf("%d-th parameter is wrong \n", -info);
        exit(1);
    }

    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N / 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("%f + %f\t", h_eigenVector[count].x, h_eigenVector[count].y);
            count++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N / 4; i++)
    {
        std::cout << h_eigenValue[i] << std::endl;
    }
    printf("\n*****************\n");

    /* free resources */
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaFree(d_idata));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaFree(d_eigenValue));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaFree(d_info));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaFree(d_work));

    CUSOLVER_CHECK(cusolverDnDestroy(cusolverH));

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamDestroy(stream));

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaDeviceReset());
}

//0.5560 + 0.0000i - 0.4864 + 0.0548i   0.8592 + 0.2101i - 1.5374 - 0.2069i
//- 0.4864 - 0.0548i   0.4317 + 0.0000i - 0.7318 - 0.2698i   1.3255 + 0.3344i
//0.8592 - 0.2101i - 0.7318 + 0.2698i   1.4099 + 0.0000i - 2.4578 + 0.2609i
//- 1.5374 + 0.2069i   1.3255 - 0.3344i - 2.4578 - 0.2609i   4.3333 + 0.0000i
void BuildMatrix(cuComplex* input)
{
    std::vector<float> realVector = { 0.5560, -0.4864, 0.8592, -1.5374, -0.4864, 0.4317, -0.7318, 1.3255,
                                    0.8592, -0.7318, 1.4099, -2.4578, -1.5374, 1.3255, -2.4578, 4.3333 };
    std::vector<float> imagVector = { 0, -0.0548, -0.2101, 0.2069, 0.0548, 0.0000, 0.2698, -0.3344,
                                     0.2101, -0.2698, 0, -0.2609, -0.2069, 0.3344, 0.2609, 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        input[i].x = realVector.at(i) * std::pow(10, 11);
        input[i].y = imagVector.at(i) * std::pow(10, 11);
    }
}
```

I raised this issue in their git ( https://github.com/NVIDIA/CUDALibrarySamples/issues/58), but unfortunately no one is answering.

If anyone can help me to solve this that will be very helpful.

Comment: "not matching at all" So you are sure the vector is not just normalized differently? It should be straightforward to check if the vector is an eigenvector both in python and CUDA. If you can provide a sample showing that this is not the case, you should report a bug. If not, this is probably just an artifact from using two different algorithms and floating point error. What happens if you use `double` instead of `float`?

Comment: I have not seen any normalization. I checked with MATLAB, CUDA result does not match with MATLAB. I validated MATLAB result by doing `A*EigenVector = EigenValue*EigenVector`. But the CUDA Eigen decomposition result does not validate this eigen decomposition equation. I checked for `double`, it gave me the same result. If you have any suggestion regarding this or any other CUDA code that I can use to solve this, that will be very helpful.

Comment: I have no experience with cusolver specifically, so I can't verify that your code is right. You seem to do proper CUDA error handling which is good. If you don't get any compiler warnings, `compute-sanitizer` (default does memcheck, enable different checks via command line flags) doesn't bring anything up and the result doesn't solve the equation, maybe you will find someone in the NVIDIA Developer Forums with the knowledge to confirm the bug or tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Just use the new sample instead of comparing to matlab results. I think the argument that the equation isn't solved is much stronger.

Comment: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/eigen-decomposition-of-hermitian-matrix-using-cusolver-does-not-match-the-result-with-matlab/204157

Comment: OP seems to have now acknowledged [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/eigen-decomposition-of-hermitian-matrix-using-cusolver-does-not-match-the-result-with-matlab/204157) that the results provided by cusolver satisfy the eigenvalue equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the post for the clear answer,
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/eigen-decomposition-of-hermitian-matrix-using-cusolver-does-not-match-the-result-with-matlab/204157

The theory tells, `A*V-lamda*V=0` should satisfy, however it might not be perfect zero. My thinking was it will very very close to `zero or e-14` somethng like this. If the equation gives a value close to zero then it is acceptable.

There are different algorithms for solving eigen decomposition, like Jacobi algorithm, Cholesky factorization... The program I provided in my post uses the function `cusolverDnCheevd` which is based on `LAPACK`. `LAPACK` doc tells that it uses `divide and conquer algorithm` to solve Hermitian matrix. Here is the link, http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/de3/group__complex_h_eeigen_ga6084b0819f9642f0db26257e8a3ebd42.html#ga6084b0819f9642f0db26257e8a3ebd42